# Query MYSQL - mysql query distinct count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
ID_PERSON   NAME_PERSON
001         JHON SLAVE
002         BRUCE WILLIAN
001         PAUL BYLING
```

I would like to know, for example, how many cases the ID_PERSON 001 is linked to different names (distinctly)

My current query:

```
SELECT ID_PERSON, COUNT(DISTINCT(NAME_PERSON))
GROUP BY ID_PERSON
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(NAME_PERSON)>1
```

The output I expect are 2 records: 001 from Jhon and 001 from Paul

As my table has millions of records, it is not performing

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM src_table t1
JOIN ( SELECT ID_PERSON
       FROM src_table t2
       GROUP BY ID_PERSON
       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(NAME_PERSON) > 1 ) t3 USING (ID_PERSON)
```

```sql
SELECT *
FROM src_table t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM src_table t2
               WHERE t1.ID_PERSON = t2.ID_PERSON
                 AND t1.NAME_PERSON <> t2.NAME_PERSON )
```

There are more variants.